# Error Output in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a question regarding SSIS. I am developing a package that performs a Data Flow task from an Excel Source into OLE DB Connection. The columns in the database contain some EMPID, Name, salary. However there is a problem in that when I enter bad data into the numeric column i.e Salary and Name in the excel spreadsheet, it will not cause the Data Flow task to redirect the false data as I would like it to. For Example If I enter "abc" into the Excel numeric column AND "123" in the Name column, It will not redirect the False Data even it stores all the data. I do want to allow this, but I'd like the package to redirect the False Data in some excel file. Please suggest. And if you provide screenshot with every step then it would be more helpful for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't done that yet you want to add another destination - like Excel destination, but I prefer CSV-style Flat File Destination for that, which I can also open in Excel.

When added, connect output red arrow from your OLE DB destination to your new destination. Then confinure your destination (connection, column mapping etc) as you would any other destination.

At last, pay attention to this:

- open your OLE DB Destination properties (double click)
- on the left, click Error Output
- in Error column of your destination input select Redirect Row

Now the errors will be redirected to your new destination.

P.S.: Sorry, no screenshots - I don't have SSIS access here.